# Why are points in my plot surrounded by a box?

Tags: plot, octave

I have the following script:

```
clear; clc
close all

# input samples
samples = rand(100,2);

# gaussian mean and covariance
mu = mean(samples);
sigma = cov(samples);

# define a 2D grid
x1 = -3:.2:3;
x2 = -3:.2:3;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
X = [X1(:) X2(:)];

# evaluate the pdf at the grid points
y = mvnpdf(X,mu,sigma);
y = reshape(y,length(x2),length(x1));

# plot iso-contours
contour(x1,x2,y,[0.0001 0.001 0.01 0.05 0.15 0.25 0.35])
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
line([0 0 1 1 0],[1 0 0 1 1],'Linestyle','--','Color','k')

# plot samples
hold on
plot(samples(:,1),samples(:,2),'+')
```

if I run it, this is the output I get:

[image]

which is mostly fine, apart from the fact that the plotted points are contoured by a box. For an esthetic reason I'd like to remove that box.

Please, can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Are you talking about the box, you plot yourself with `line(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer (since that has been answered in the comments), but writing this as an answer since it's difficult to put code in comments.

I just wanted to say, since you mentioned 'aesthetics', that you can usually make a really big difference in your graph presentation with minimal extra effort. E.g.

```
clear; clc; clf
figure(1)

# input samples
samples = rand(100,2);

# gaussian mean and covariance
mu = mean(samples);
sigma = cov(samples);

# define a 2D grid
x1 = -3:.2:3;
x2 = -3:.2:3;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
X = [X1(:) X2(:)];

# evaluate the pdf at the grid points
y = mvnpdf(X,mu,sigma);
y = reshape(y,length(x2),length(x1));

# plot iso-contours
contour(x1,x2,y,[0.0001 0.001 0.01 0.05 0.15 0.25 0.35], 'linewidth', 3);
set(gcf, 'color', [0.75,0.75,0.75]);
set(gca, 'color', 'k');
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')

# plot samples
hold on
h = plot(samples(:,1),samples(:,2), 'o', 'markerfacecolor', [0, 0.6, 1], ...
         'markeredgecolor', [0, .4, .8], 'linewidth', 1.5, 'markersize', 7);
axis tight auto equal square;
```

[image]